# How I can select highest review from a user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to select reviews for product, but **unique by user** *(i.e. one review from user)*.

With my code, I select all reviews, and I can see few reviews left by one user.

```
SELECT 
    tr.reviewText, tr.reviewDate, tr.reviewRating,
    u.userName AS userName,
    u.userFirstName AS userFirstName, u.userSurname AS userSurname, 
    u.countryId AS countryId
FROM 
    tblReviews tr
INNER JOIN 
    tblOrderProduct op ON op.orderProductId = tr.orderProductId
                       AND op.productOptionId IN (SELECT productOptionId 
                                                  FROM tblProductOption
                                                  WHERE productSubCuId = 111 
                                                    AND productOptionActive = 1)
LEFT JOIN 
    tblOrder o ON o.orderId = op.orderId
LEFT JOIN 
    tblUser u ON u.userRandomId = o.userRandomId
WHERE 
    tr.reviewsStatusId = 2
ORDER BY 
    tr.reviewRating DESC, tr.reviewDate DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

Can I get just one review from each user?

Maybe I need select `userId` -> group results by `userId` and select one per group? *[I tried to do so, but I didn't succeed :( ]*

Comment: You want to return one random review form each user? Perhaps the *last* review for each user? Or, for each product, one review for each user of that product (removing additional reviews by the same user)?

Comment: you want see the last  review for each user?  . is not clear ... add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: @scsimon for each product, one review for each user of that product (removing additional reviews by the same user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to number the reviews and select any one like below:

```
;with per_user_one_review
as
(SELECT tr.reviewText, tr.reviewDate, tr.reviewRating,
        u.userName as userName,
        u.userFirstName as userFirstName, u.userSurname as userSurname, 
        u.countryId as countryId, row_number() over (partition by u.userRandomId order by tr.reviewDate desc) rn
      FROM tblReviews tr
      INNER JOIN tblOrderProduct op 
        ON op.orderProductId = tr.orderProductId
      AND op.productOptionId IN (
        SELECT productOptionId FROM tblProductOption
        WHERE productSubCuId = 111 AND productOptionActive = 1
      )
      LEFT JOIN tblOrder o ON o.orderId = op.orderId
      LEFT JOIN tblUser u ON u.userRandomId = o.userRandomId
      WHERE tr.reviewsStatusId = 2
      ORDER BY tr.reviewRating DESC, tr.reviewDate DESC
      OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
      )
select * from per_user_one_review where rn = 1
```

It will pick the latest review (`reviewDate desc`) from the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the last review  you could use a join with the suquery for max review date grouped  by orderProductId

(and as a suggestion you could use a inner join instead of a IN clasue based on a subquery)

```
    select tr.reviewText
            , tr.reviewDate
            , tr.reviewRating
            , u.userName
            , u.userFirstName 
            , u.userSurname 
            , u.countryId 
    from  tblReviews tr 
    INNER JOIN (
        select max(reviewDate) max_date, orderProductId
        from tblReviews 
        group by orderProductId
    ) t1 on t1.orderProductId = tr.orderProductId and t1.max_date = tr.reviewDate
    INNER JOIN tblOrderProduct op ON op.orderProductId = tr.orderProductId
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT productOptionId 
        FROM tblProductOption
        WHERE productSubCuId = 111 AND productOptionActive = 1
    ) t2 ON op.productOptionId = t2.productOptionId
    LEFT JOIN tblOrder o ON o.orderId = op.orderId
    LEFT JOIN tblUser u ON u.userRandomId = o.userRandomId
    WHERE tr.reviewsStatusId = 2
    ORDER BY tr.reviewRating DESC, tr.reviewDate DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```